# Project structure for component-based architecture in AngularJS 1.5

Tags: angularjs

What is standard project folder structure should I follow for making a component-based project in AngularJS 1.5?

Comment: Please give some of your code that you tried. And for theoretical suggestions. Please stackexachange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my question, I have tried and make beautiful project struct. but it depends on a developer which type of structure they want to follow.

```
   /app
    /component
       /login
         login.component.js
         login.html
       /signup
         signup.component.js
         signup.html 

    /layout
      /img
      /css

    /bower_components
    index.html
bower.json
```

Comment: I like it. I have implemented same structure in my codeship.

Answer (score 0):

You can have following type of basic folder structure and also refer to [git app starter](https://github.com/jofftiquez/angular-app-starter-pack)

```
/app
    /scripts
            /controllers
            /directives
            /services
            /filters
            app.js
    /views
    /styles
    /img
    /bower_components
    index.html
bower.json
```

Comment: It is used for making the simple project in angular but I want to make the component-based project structure.